# Did the Sith know of Force ghosts?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, sith, force-ghost

One of the primary goals of a Sith is to achieve immortality.

So my question is:
Did the Sith know that the Jedi could become immortal by becoming a Force ghost? And, if so, did any Sith try to replicate this?

(I know that Sith can bind their Force energy to certain items but that's not a Force ghost.)

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/113212/76048

Comment: @F1Krazy Not if Sith **can** become one (*because they can't*) but if they know that Jedi **do** become one

Comment: What canon level are you comfortable with?  Movies, Disney canon, or Legends? Edit: I guess not Legends, based on your insistence that Sith can't become Force ghosts (since Legends canon directly contradicts that).

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet yeah, more Disney canon than Legends

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [Legends](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_ghost), Lord Vader learned of the existence of Force Ghosts from Darth Sidious, and since the Sith in that continuity had many, many instances of the Sith attaching their spirits/essence to objects or locations, it's logical to assume that both sides knew of the other's versions of "immortality" *when they were both at the height of their power* and that there was at least some ancient Sith record of Force Ghosts, or else Palpatine acquired his knowledge from the ransacked Jedi Temple after Order 66.

In [Canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_spirit), however, it's not readily apparent if the Sith knew about Force Ghosts, because so much of the EU has been excised and so far relatively little has been reinstated about the ancient Sith. Sith were unable to *learn how*, but that does not preclude the ability to learn *of*. That said, it's still reasonable to think that since at least one known Sith, [Lord Momin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Momin), was, as you said, able to imbue an object with his Force essence/spirit, the ancient Sith knew of similar techniques to becoming a Force Ghost and preserving their spirits after death.

Comment: This looks like it would be a good answer if you can provide links to support both claims.

Comment: While this all seems essentially correct I think it's also worth noting that one of the fundamental metaphysical disagreements between the Jedi & Sith is that the Sith believe that nothing exists beyond the physical universe; that death is the end, hence Sith going to great lengths to prolong their lives.Things like Momin's mask, "Eternal Rur", and the witch's alter on Dathomir appear to be techno-mantic methods of "living" after physical deaths. If I had to guess I'd say such apparitions aren't at all the same as force ghosts. Mere illusions and echos, not connected to the Cosmic Force.

Answer (score 0):

Sith certainly seem to know about it. 
In certain books and TV shows, Sith have shown knowledge of them. For example, they have long spoke of the ghosts at Korriban, and in Sith lore there are many references to them. Whether they can see Jedi ghosts is another, separate Matter.

About the second question, Sith do have ways of coming back, but don’t use them in the way Jedi do. Like Jedi, Sith seem to believe in an afterlife, sometimes known as Chaos. It is implied somtimes that some Sith can’t escape it, as a sort of punishment. The dark side is sometimes said to have negative effect on the wielded too.